# Iterating tab delimited file fails (loop runs only once)

Tags: python, csv, for-loop

I'm very new to python and having trouble with this bit of code that I wrote:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python


OutFileName = "k_values.txt"

OutFile = open(OutFileName, 'w')
with open("structure_working.txt") as infile:
    for Line in open("structure_working.txt"):
        Line = Line.strip('\n')
        ElementList = Line.split('\t')
        k1 = ElementList[2]
        k2 = ElementList[3]
        k3 = ElementList[4]
        k4 = ElementList[5]
        k = 1
         if k2 > k:
            k = 2
         if k3 > k2:
            k = 3
         if k4 > k3:
            k = 4
        name = ElementList[1]
        OutputString = "%s\t%s" % (name, k)
        print OutputString
        OutFile.write(OutputString + "\n")

OutFile.close()
```

My input file is a tab delimited file.  The problem is that my for loop only runs once over the header line and doesn't continue into the body of the file.  Here is an example of my text file:

```
     num    indiv   1   2   3   4   k   
     1  JB1972  0.642   0.141   0.091   0.127       
     2  JB1973  0.754   0.113   0.079   0.055       
     3  JB1974  0.069   0.422   0.418   0.091       
     4  JB1976  0.175   0.339   0.249   0.237       
     5  JB1977  0.149   0.365   0.383   0.103       
     6  JB1978  0.421   0.184   0.146   0.249       
     7  JB1979  0.264   0.246   0.395   0.095       
     8  JB1980  0.074   0.511   0.287   0.128       
     9  JB1981  0.083   0.162   0.275   0.48        
    10  JB1982  0.059   0.145   0.73    0.067
```

None of the answers I've found to the problem "for loop only runs once" were helpful to my specific problem.  The fact that the code works on the header line makes me think that the problem is with the for loop.  Any ideas?

Comment: its reading line by line, so header will run only ones

Comment: If you have a comma/space/tab delimited file, you should use csv and your code doesnt make any sense, what are you trying to do?

Comment: A few problems here: You're opening you're file `structure_working.txt` twice: once as `infile` in the context manager, and then again in your for loop. Also, you shouldn't use uppercase letters in variable names. The comparisons against `k` will not work as expected, because you're comparing strings and ints.

Comment: you have an indentation problem `if k2 > k:` all such `if`s are over-indented by one space

Comment: I'm trying to assign a k value from a STRUCTURE run to each individual.  The highest number in each line gets assigned as the k-value.

Comment: You cannot reasonably compare `k` (an int) to `k1` (a string). anyway, that's not the cause of your original problem. But maybe you could come up with a cleaner example of what's not working

Comment: The indentation problems make me think this isn't the actual code.

Comment: Someone should have asked if there's an error message popping up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is repeating the opening of the input file twice, unnecessarily

```
with open("structure_working.txt") as infile:
    for Line in open("structure_working.txt"):
```

Replace such lines with

```
with open("structure_working.txt") as infile:
    for Line in infile
```

Problem #1: all the `if`s are over-indented by one space.

Problem #2: you aren't skipping the header

Here is the code, a bit tidier

```
outfileName = "k_values.txt"
with open("structure_working.txt") as infile, open(outfileName, 'w') as outfile:
    next(infile) # skip the header
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip('\n')
        elementlist = line.split()
        k = max(enumerate(elementlist[2:], start=1), key=lambda t: t[1])[0]
        name = elementlist[1]
        outputstring = "{}\t{}".format(name, k)
        print outputstring
        outfile.write(outputstring + "\n")
```

With an input file of

```
num    indiv   1   2   3   4   k
1  JB1972  0.642   0.141   0.091   0.127
2  JB1973  0.754   0.113   0.079   0.055
3  JB1974  0.069   0.422   0.418   0.091
4  JB1976  0.175   0.339   0.249   0.237
5  JB1977  0.149   0.365   0.383   0.103
6  JB1978  0.421   0.184   0.146   0.249
7  JB1979  0.264   0.246   0.395   0.095
8  JB1980  0.074   0.511   0.287   0.128
9  JB1981  0.083   0.162   0.275   0.48
10  JB1982  0.059   0.145   0.73    0.067
```

it produces

```
JB1972  1
JB1973  1
JB1974  2
JB1976  2
JB1977  3
JB1978  1
JB1979  3
JB1980  2
JB1981  4
JB1982  3
```

i.e. for each line it indicates the column with the highest value

By the way, please respect the [PEP-8 guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) on variable naming.

Comment: I just corrected it per your suggestion, and still the same result.  Thanks, though.

Comment: see my edit for a new and improved version of the code :)

Answer (score 1):

You should change your code to something like the following (untested) example:

```
import csv

# use with statement for file handling
# note that nesting is also possible and kind of convenient
with open(outfname, 'w+') as outf, open(infname) as inf:
    # use csv.reader and csv.writer to specify csv file format
    # also have a look at csv.DictReader (I like it much better...)
    reader = csv.reader(inf, delimiter='\t')
    writer = csv.writer(outf, delimiter='\t')
    # skip the header line (not necessary when csv.DictReader is used)
    reader.next()
    # iterate input lines
    for line in reader:
        # split line without having to deal with the proper formatting
        name = line[1]
        # somehow compute k value (probably I haven't got it right)
        k = max(enumerate(map(float, line[2:6])), 1), key=lambda x:x[1])[0]
        # write row without having to deal with proper formatting
        writer.writerow([name, k])
```

Use the with-statement for handling files whenever possible. They provide easy to use wrapper for fail-safe automatic closing and a clean syntax (in my opinion). Note that it's also possible and convenient to nest multiple files within one with-block.

You are reading a csv file (character separated values). Python provides a module for that in its standard library (you should use the standard library whenever possible). Also take into account frameworks like `pandas` they also provide functions for convenient handling of csv (or excel) files.

When you have properly dealt with the problem of reading and writing csv files you can finally go and revisit your logic of computing the `k` value. As you can see in my example, I have converted the strings from the input file to numbers before comparing them. Further I have assumed that you want to get the column number of the maximum value, so I have tried to implement that. When you try to implement something like that, again, please have a look at what functionality the standard library offers (beyond if-statements). This will greatly improve your life (and code quality). I have put some links to the documentation below for a start.

For reference:

- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html
- http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max
- [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/1025391)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this

```
#! /usr/bin/env python


OutFileName = "k_values.txt"

OutFile = open(OutFileName, 'w')
with open("structure_working.txt") as infile:
    for Line in infile:
# the rest seems ok
```

Comment: true, but that doesn't solve the problem at all. There are a few more things to fix